# Strictly increasing sequence in $\mathcal P(\omega)/fin$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Is it possible to find a sequence $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha < \omega_1}$ in $\mathcal P(\omega)$ with the following property:

(1) If $\alpha  < \beta$, then $|A_\alpha \setminus A_\beta|$ is finite but $|A_\beta \setminus A_\alpha|$ is infinite;

$\mathcal P(\omega)$ is the powerset of $\omega$. I'm really at a loss as to how to approach this, so any hints are appreciated. For what it's worth, an affirmative answer to this question was assumed in an answer to another question of mine at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376336/does-set-of-finitely-additive-probability-measures-embed-linearly-into-a-strictl).

Comment: Are you asking about the "Pick a strictly ascending sequence in $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$" bit of that answer? If so, note that you haven't really presented the relevant question correctly here. An ascending $\omega_1$-sequence in $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$ is an $\omega_1$-sequence of sets $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ such that for every $\alpha<\beta<\omega_1$ we have $(i)$ $A_\alpha\setminus A_\beta$ is finite and $(ii)$ $A_\beta\setminus A_\alpha$ is infinite (that is, $A_\alpha$ is "mod finite" a subset of $A_\beta$ but $A_\beta$ is *not* "mod finite" a subset of $A_\alpha$).

Comment: In particular your $(1)$ is far too strong: there is no $\subset$-increasing $\omega_1$-sequence of sets of naturals at all.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh okay, thanks! I think I am just ignorant of the terminology.

Comment: @aduh: You could write $A_\alpha\subset^*A_\beta$, meaning that $|A\setminus B|<\omega=|B\setminus A|$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Okay, I will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recursively construct sets $B_\xi$ for $\xi<\omega_1$ so that $B_\eta\subset^*B_\xi$ whenever $\xi<\eta<\omega_1$ and then let $A_\xi=\omega\setminus B_\xi$ for each $\xi<\omega_1$. (Here $X\subset^*Y$ means that $|X\setminus Y|<\omega=|Y\setminus X|$.)

Suppose that $\eta<\omega_1$, and we have infinite subsets $B_\xi$ of $\omega$ for $\xi<\eta$ such that $B_\xi\subset^*B_\zeta$ whenever $\zeta<\xi<\eta$. Enumerate $\{B_\xi:\xi<\eta\}$ as $\{C_k:k\in\omega\}$, recursively choose distinct $m_k,n_k\in\omega$ so that $m_k,n_k\in\bigcap_{i\le k}C_i$ for each $k\in\omega$, let $B_\eta=\{n_k:k\in\omega\}$, and check that $B_\eta\subset^*B_\xi$ for each $\xi<\eta$.